# POST method only working with empty action

Tags: forms, post

I am trying to send a form via post-method, and with the action

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"
```

but it is only working if i leave the action blank. This is still reloading the page, just as PHP_SELF. But could this lead to any problems?
Btw, when I use get-method, the action can be PHP_SELF.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] returns the name of script. You probably mean $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. It is working with actoin because most of browsers will submit it to the same page when there is no action attribute.

Comment: But why is PHP_SELF working with GET? If it's not the correct url it should work with none of the two actions, right?